# ntablewrapper is null or not an object error in ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, datatable

I am newbie to jquery data table and i am trying to resolve an error in ie8 due to fn.destroy in datatable.

Its working fine in firefox but in ie8 on using oTable.fnDestroy its throwing an error 'ntablewrapper' is null or not an object in jquery.datatable.js line number 5410.

I am using version 1.9.4 of jquery.datatable.js.

And if i remove oTable.fnDestroy then error will not be there but datatable not reinitialized and nothing is displayed on page.

Here is my code.

```
var oTable = $('#sample_editable_1').dataTable();
oTable.fnDestroy();
oTable = $('#sample_editable_1').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {},
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
    oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
        "dataType": 'json',
        "type": "POST",
        "url": sSource,
        "data": aoData,
        "success": function(data){}
    }
});
```

Is there any way to resolve this problem or any replacement for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Although late to reply hope it helps to someone.

Change small dataTable() to **D**ataTable()